# How to change menu background color of Tkinter's OptionMenu widget?

Tags: python, tkinter, optionmenu

If I take a simple example of OptionMenu from http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/optionmenu.htm, and add a line that sets background color (see below), only the button background changes color, not the drop-down menu which remains gray.  Can I set color for both the button and the menu of OptionMenu?

I am using Windows 7, Python 2.6.6, Tkinter Rev 73770

```
from Tkinter import *  
master = Tk()  
variable = StringVar(master)  
variable.set("one") # default value  
w = OptionMenu(master, variable, "one", "two", "three")  
w.config(bg = "GREEN")  # Set background color to green  
w.pack()  
mainloop()
```

Thank you

Answer (score 24):

You need to grab the `menu` object from the `OptionMenu` and set its background color.  This should accomplish what you want...

```
w = OptionMenu(master, variable, "one", "two", "three")  
w.config(bg = "GREEN")  # Set background color to green

# Set this to what you want, I'm assuming "green"...
w["menu"].config(bg="GREEN")

w.pack()
```

Comment: On M1 using 3.10.0b1, you don't have to include the object via `["menu"]` but still need to configure after initialisation.

Answer (score 6):

I add my answer a little late but I would like to add a clarification!

As @Bryan well said, the command to change the background and foreground color is fine:

```
 w["menu"].config(bg="GREEN")
```

But this command actually only affects the drop-down menu when clicked, as can be seen in this image:

[image: Drop-down menu background color only when clicked]

With Tkinter the command to set attributes to the window without it being clicked is:

```
w.config(bg="GREEN")
```

[image: Drop-down menu background color without it being clicked]

It's therefore necessary to combine the two lines of code to have a completely green drop-down menu!

```
w.config(bg="GREEN")
w["menu"].config(bg="GREEN")
```

But there is still a problem because if you put your cursor on the button to open the menu then it resumes its default white color...

[image: Drop-down menu background color when cursor above]

As well as the ugly blue color:

[image: Drop-down menu background color when cursor above]

Fortunately there is a parameter for the .config() function to correct this problem:

```
w.config(bg="GREEN", fg="BLACK", activebackground="GREEN", activeforeground="BLACK")
w["menu"].config(bg="GREEN", fg="BLACK", activebackground="GREEN", activeforeground="BLACK")
```

So here is the method to have a green drop-down menu in the background and black for the menu entries. But you can modify the parameters of the .config() function as you wish! (like width, height, font, font size,...)

I hope I was understanding enough for beginners in Tkinter like me! :)