# How to change or remove submenu border of Tkinter's OptionMenu widget?

Tags: python, tkinter, submenu, optionmenu

I'm trying to get rid of the thick border showing up when I changed the optionmenu and submenu background and foreground color.

I did manage to get rid or modify the parent optionmenu border by using:

optmenu.configure(hilightthickness=0)

There's a reference here changing the background color of the submenu:

[How to change menu background color of Tkinter's OptionMenu widget?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6178153/how-to-change-menu-background-color-of-tkinters-optionmenu-widget)

..but I can't seem to find a way to remove the outer border showing up on the submenu. Tried hilighthickness=0 but it's no good.

I'm using Windows 7 and Python 2.7.

Any ideas? thanks.

Comment: There was a similar question recently made that had a good answer, https://stackoverflow.com/a/62416450/10062180

Answer (score 0):

There should be a bd option, just do something like:

```
bd=0
```

Just add it when you are defining all the options for it.