# get rid of white border around option menu

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk, tkinter.optionmenu

I'm trying to get rid of the white border around the `OptionMenu`.

## What I tried

I changed the colour to red, but there is still a white border around it.

Can anyone help?

[image]

## Here's the code:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('500x500')
var = StringVar()
option = ttk.OptionMenu(root,var,'1','2','3')
option["menu"].config(bg="red")
option.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Also, is there a way to change the colour of the `OptionMenu` trigger box (In the red Circle)?
[image]

Comment: Have you tried setting the borderwidth to zero?

Comment: I just done ```option["menu"].config(bg="red",borderwidth=0)``` nothing changed unfortunately,

Comment: Could not reproduce with the given code example

Comment: The window is not blue, but the menu is red demonstrating the grey border.

Comment: Have you considered writing your own option menu?

Comment: @Mike-SMT That might be more difficult than you think.

Comment: @Mike-SMT From the effbot Menu documentation: "Since this widget uses native code where possible, you shouldn’t try to fake menus using buttons and other Tkinter widgets."

Comment: @MinionJim Consider, however, that there is no option to remove a border from the effbot Menu documentation.

Comment: @MinionJim Maybe but that has not stopped me from doing the same with other widgets. I had to build a custom scroll bar and that was no simple task but filled my needs where the tk widget could not. I would need to do some digging of my own to see how complex an option menu really is but I do not see why one cannot create their own.

Comment: Yes, @MinionJim The only option is to create a custom option menu. No other alternative.

Comment: I just ran your code with Python 3.8.2. I get no white border, but a lovely soft shadow effect. So whatever you do may not survive the next Python upgrade you do.

Comment: Let me run with python 3.8

Comment: I don't see any shadow @MikeO'Connor

Comment: I get it only when I click on the 1 in the listbox (or whatever it's called). The soft shadow is formed around the red box that drops down. So do you get a white border @TheMaker?

Comment: @MikeO'Connor Are you talking about the OP's code, or my code?

Comment: @MikeO'Connor Cause if you are, then there is also a shadow _as well_ as a  grey border.

Comment: @TheMaker, I just copied the code below "Here's the code:" So I'm saying that with Python3.8.2 the white border doesn't occur. No problem to fix, in other words.

Comment: @MinionJim I have fixed the code for the menu. It should work now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As stated in the comments by @Mike-SMT,

> Have you considered writing your own option menu?

This, to me, seems to be the only way to get an `OptionMenu` without having that irritating grey border.

Here is my attempt at it:

```py
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('500x500')

class custom_option_menu(tk.Tk):

    def down(self, *menu_items):
        if self.button["text"] == "↓":
            self.frame.place(x = self.x + (len(self.first) * 13)/2, y = self.y + 50, anchor = "center")
            self.button.config(text = "↑")

        elif self.button["text"] == "↑":
            self.frame.place_forget()
            self.button.config(text = "↓")

    def __init__(self, master, first, bg, *menu_items):

        self.master = master
        self.first = first
        self.menu_items = menu_items
        self.bg = bg
        self.frame = tk.Frame(master, height = 100, width = 100)
        self.otherframe = tk.Frame(master, height = 10, width = len(first) * 13)
        self.label = tk.Label(self.otherframe, text = str(first))
        self.button = tk.Button(self.otherframe, text = "↓", command = lambda: self.down(), relief= "flat")
        def save_var(event = "<Button-1>"):
            print(event.widget["text"])
        for i in range(len(self.menu_items)):
            self.frame.config(bg = self.bg)
            self.option = tk.Button(self.frame, text = self.menu_items[i], relief = "flat", bg = self.bg, textvariable = int(i))
            self.option.pack()
            self.option.bind("<Button-1>", save_var)





    def put(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.button.pack(side = "right")
        self.label.pack()
        self.frame.place(x = x + (len(self.first) * 13)/2, y = y + 50, anchor = "center")

        self.frame.place_forget()
        self.otherframe.place(x = x + (len(self.first) * 13)/2, y = y, anchor = "center")

nice = custom_option_menu(root, "o000000000000000", "blue", "First", "second", "Third")
nice.put(100, 200)
root.mainloop()
```

Sadly I couldn't get the default geometry managers to work for this, so I created `.put()`. It's just the x and y coordinates.

The arguments to the class `custom_option_menu` go as follows:

The first argument is the parent widget.

The second argument is the text on the `OptionMenu`.

The third argument is the background color for the options.

The remaining arguments are the options.

To open the menu, click the down arrow.

I hope this is what you were looking for!

Comment: Consider bind an event `<Leave>` to make it disappear.

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA Okay, how do I do that? How do I use ```<Leave>```.

Comment: FYI, I know the menu is buggy, I am working on fixing it.

Comment: @TheMaker, I appreciate the effort you have put into this answer, though it is quite sad that it is built on assumptions (character width of 13, button height of 50, text of main button not changing, etc.). Despite this, it did indeed "remove the grey border around the Menu part of the OptionMenu" so I have awarded you the bounty.

Comment: @MinionJim Thanks mate!! It took me a day, and I will improve on the widget.

Answer (score -3):

Try `option["highlightthickness"]=0`. That should remove the border.

Comment: This removes the border around the button (which would help with the part about setting the bg of the trigger box), not the border on the menu.

Comment: Thanks for that, so you don't know how to solve the one before?

Comment: This configuration only works on tk.OptionMenu not ttk.OptionMenu. The OP is using ttk here.

Comment: @Mike-SMT I tried this on tk.OptionMenu. It still doesn't work.

Comment: @TheMaker I was only saying that the `highlightthickness` is only available to tk not ttk. I know it doesn't solve your issue.

Comment: @Mike-SMT I don't have this issue